# Common large PST files to test big data

Tags: dataset, pst

I need a large corpus of PST files (may in GB or TB's) with more mails to test my big data application.

I found only [Enron data set](http://www.edrm.net/resources/data-sets/edrm-enron-email-data-set). Is any other common PST file available to test ?

Share me PST download links.

Comment: The direct link to the [Enron data set](http://info.nuix.com/EnronDownload2013.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test size and validity, you can create a PST and literally copy any big file directly into a folder (tested on Office 365 Pro)

Answer (score -1):

You could create large dummy files, attach them to e-mails, save them as draft?

To create a dummy file, from a command prompt, execute this:

```
fsutil file createnew filename length
```

Example:

```
fsutil file createnew test.txt 52428800
```